# Reading date vector with different formats: Matlab

Tags: matlab, date

Consider a cell array of dates `date = { 1000000 x 1 }` such that it has dates in different formats.

```
 date = 27-01-2009
        28-Mar-2003
            .
            .
            .
        21-02-2003 06:35:20
        21-02-2003 06:35:20.42
            .
            .
         and so on
```

How do I get the a `100000x3` matrix `A = [ year month day ]` from `date`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Approach 1**

```
date = {
    '27-01-2009'
    '28-Mar-2003'
    '21-02-2003 06:35:20'
    '21-02-2003 06:35:20.42'}

date_double_arr = datevec(date,'dd-mm-yyyy')
out = date_double_arr(:,1:3) %// desired output
```

Output -

```
out =
        2009           1          27
        2003           3          28
        2003           2          21
        2003           2          21
```

**Approach 2**

In case of inconsistencies between the date-month-year and time, one might want to seperate out the former group and use them to get the final Nx3 array like so -

```
t1 = cellfun(@(x) strsplit(x,' '), date,'uni',0)
t2 = cellfun(@(x) x(1), t1)
t3 = datevec(t2,'dd-mm-yyyy')
out = t3(:,1:3) %// desired output
```

Comment: Hey Divakar. I tried that out before. I get the this error.

     Error using dtstr2dtvecmx
     Failed on converting date string to date number.

     Error in datevec (line 118)
            y = dtstr2dtvecmx(t,icu_dtformat);

Comment: @Nishanth What version of MATLAB are you using?

Comment: I'm using MATLAB R2013b.

Comment: @Nishanth Could you run with the `date{4x1}` that I have used in the code and see if it works? This could clear out few things. I am on 2014a BTW.

Comment: @Nishanth Ok I guess there are some cells in your bigger date cell array that are not "consistent", maybe some empty cells or some cells that have only two of those three fields present or the hyphens between these three fields are missing?

Comment: @Nishanth Check out if the just added `Edit 1` works for you.

Comment: The edit works! However, there are some empty cells which are the problem. I just picked out the emptys using `i1 = ismember(date,'')` and removed them.

Comment: @Nishanth Hmm interesting!

Comment: @Nishanth BTW since it was confirmed to be working, it might be wise to click on the accept checkmark :)